# CSV Feeders for gatling 3

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling, gatling-plugin

I am using Gatling 3. I have a csv feeder with just one column titled accountIds. I need to pass this in the body of my POST request as JSON. I have tried a lot of different syntax but nothing seems to be working. I can also not print what is actually being sent in the body. It works if I remove the "$accountIds" and use an actual value instead. Below is my code:

```
val searchFeeder = csv("C://data/accountids.csv").random

val scn1 = scenario("Scenario 1")
  .feed(searchFeeder)
  .exec(http("Search")
  .post("/v3/accounts/")
     .body(StringBody("""{"accountIds": "${accountIds}"}""")).asJson)

setUp(scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(10)).protocols(httpConf))
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of the CSV?

Comment: accountIds

CE6263114

CE6434015

GL12INGB0

BE7837745

BE7737740

BE1036346

Comment: This is a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled trace level in logback.xml to see the details of post request?
Also, can you confirm if location you have mentioned "C://data/accountids.csv" is the right one. Generally, data folder resides in project location and within project you can access the data file as:
 val searchFeeder = csv("data/stack.csv").random

I just created sample script and enabled logging.I am able to see that accountId is getting passed:

```
package basicpackage
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation

class StackFeeder extends Simulation {

  val httpConf=http.baseUrl("http://example.com")

  val searchFeeder = csv("data/stack.csv").random

  val scn1 = scenario("Scenario 1")
    .feed(searchFeeder)
    .exec(http("Search")
      .post("/v3/accounts/")
      .body(StringBody("""{"accountIds": "${accountIds}"}""")).asJson)

  setUp(scn1.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))
```

[csv file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWCRE.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think this solves the problem.